# How to update text using timer in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, alert, swiftui

I have text in view now i want to update that text using alert on every second.

Here is code i have done.

```
struct CountDownView : View {
    var body: some View {       
        VStack{
            Text("Update text with timer").lineLimit(nil).padding(20)

            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("WWDC"), displayMode:.automatic)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i have managed to update text using alert.

i have declared date as `State` so whenever date is changed using alert text will also get updated.

```swift
struct CurrentDateView : View {
    @State var newDate = Date()

    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .current, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(newDate)")
            .onReceive(timer) {
                self.newDate = Date()
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. I've seen this approach described on blogs etc., but it's wrong.

Comment: @matt what is the best possible approach?

Comment: matt has provided a link -- `Nice. For an alternative (related) approach, see my stackoverflow.com/a/56905649/341994. – matt `

Comment: @matt Can you elaborate why this approach is "incorrect"?

Comment: it works for me, but my code is a bit different. This code is just syntatically incorrect

Answer (score 36):

Using Combine:

```swift
struct CurrentDateView : View {
    @State var now = Date()

    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .current, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(now)")
            .onReceive(timer) {
                self.now = Date()
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. For an alternative (related) approach, see my https://stackoverflow.com/a/56905649/341994.

Comment: You need to access to the variable 'now' (in any way) inside the body. If you change Text("\(now)") to Text("\(Date())") the View is not going to update.

Comment: Got it. Just define the publisher as follows:
let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .current, in: .common).autoconnect().first

Comment: How to make the timer only fire once?

Comment: If you go this route you'll need to invalidate the timer when you switch views. Otherwise it's going to keep firing with unexpected results.

Comment: I found "Generic parameter 'P' could not be inferred" when I added .onReceive to my code.

Comment: @BonoLv just define closure explicitly like .onReceive(timer) { _ in ... }

Answer (score 1):

the original sample was at:

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-a-timer-with-swiftui

I do use this approach to update from one of my calls periodically...

see also at:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/replacing-foundation-timers-with-timer-publishers

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var msg = ""

var body: some View {

    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .current, in: .common).autoconnect()

    Text(msg)
        .onReceive(timer) { input in
            msg = MyManager.shared.ifo ?? "not yet received"
        }
}
```

}

I do I haver to call network in other ways, but here I simply call periodically some of my managers.

To stop timer (as in link from hackingSwift..) You can use:

```
            self.timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
```