# getting unresolved identifier 'self' in SwiftUI code trying to use Timer.scheduledTimer

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

In SwiftUI I'm noting to use a Timer that:

Try 1 - This doesn't work as get "Use of unresolved identifier 'self'"

```
var timer2: Timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) {
    self.angle = self.angle + .degrees(1)
}
```

Try 2 - Works, but have to put in an "_ = self.timer" to start it later

```
var timer: Timer {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) {_ in
        self.angle = self.angle + .degrees(1)
    }
}
// then after need to use " .onAppear(perform: {_ = self.timer}) "
```

Is there a way to get my Try1 working?  That is where in a SwiftUI file I can create the timer up front?  Or actually where in SwiftUI would one normally start and stop the timer?  i.e. where are lifecycle methods

Whole file:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {

    @State var angle: Angle = .degrees(55)

//    var timer2: Timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) {
//        self.angle = self.angle + .degrees(1)
//    }

    var timer: Timer {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) {_ in
            self.angle = self.angle + .degrees(1)
        }
    }

    private func buttonAction() {
        print("test")
        self.angle = self.angle + .degrees(5)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Start")
            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.blue)
                    .frame(
                        width: .init(integerLiteral: 100),
                        height: .init(integerLiteral: 100)
                    )
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.green)
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 100)
                    // .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 25.0))
                    .rotationEffect(self.angle)
            }
            Button(action: self.buttonAction) {
                Text("CLICK HERE")
            }
            Text("End")
        }
         .onAppear(perform: {_ = self.timer})

    }
}
```

Comment: `lazy var timer2: Timer = ...`.

Comment: get "Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter" with "lazy var timer2: Timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in
        self.angle = self.angle + .degrees(1)
    }"

Comment: any suggestions for how you would incorporate a timer to slowly spin a rectangle in a swiftui view in a best practice sense?

Comment: It isn't clear to me that you need a timer at all, since this is an animation. If you're going to use a timer, personally I would run the timer elsewhere and use the `publish` method.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56956224/341994 for the sort of thing I mean.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It isn't clear to me that you need a timer for your example, but since there is a great deal of misinformation out there about how to include a Timer in a SwiftUI app, I'll demonstrate.

The key is to put the timer elsewhere and publish each time it fires. We can easily do this by adding a class that holds the timer as a bindable object to our environment (note that you will need to import Combine):

```
class TimerHolder : BindableObject {
    var timer : Timer!
    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<TimerHolder,Never>()
    var count = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.didChange.send(self)
        }
    }
    func start() {
        self.timer?.invalidate()
        self.count = 0
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { 
            [weak self] _ in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.count += 1
        }
    }
}
```

We will need to pass an instance of this class down through the environment, so we modify the scene delegate:

```
window.rootViewController = 
    UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
```

becomes

```
window.rootViewController = 
    UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView()
        .environmentObject(TimerHolder()))
```

Finally, lets put up some UI that starts the timer and displays the count, to prove that it is working:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @EnvironmentObject var timerHolder : TimerHolder
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Start Timer") { self.timerHolder.start() }
            Text(String(self.timerHolder.count))
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT** Update for those who have not been following the plot: BindableObject has migrated into ObservableObject, and there is no need any more for manual signalling. So:

```
class TimerHolder : ObservableObject {
    var timer : Timer!
    @Published var count = 0
    // ... and the rest is as before ...
```

Comment: thanks very much.  Is the "environmentObject(TimerHolder())" kind of the standard way in SwiftUI to instantiate worker type objects you may want running and available to any view then I guess?  (I'll have to read up).   Also do you need "combine" here?  Which part is actually the the new "combine" framework?

Comment: "kind of the standard way" Well, it's more or less what Apple does in their examples, so I'd have to say yes. "Also do you need Combine here?" You tell me. Try deleting it and see what happens.

Comment: But see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/56956224/341994 which may be a better approach.

Comment: `Timer.publish` is a better approach, but calling `Timer.publish` in a `View`'s constructor (as in that linked answer) is **bad**.

Comment: Why is calling `Timer.publish` **bad** in a view contractor? @robmayoff

Comment: Because, depending on how you use your view, SwiftUI might recreate the view, which starts a new `Timer`, which isn’t synchronized with the old timer.

Comment: This works but I had to change **var count = 0 ** to **@Published var count**

Comment: Is this still working? Can someone update this code?

Comment: @Eddy, sure, it's just as in the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/59493527/341994, BindableObject has migrated into ObservableObject since those days. I've added that.

Comment: @matt can you answer my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62490734/assigning-an-observedstate-s-published-value-to-a-state it’s something related to the TimeHolder (I just named it TimeWrapper)

Answer (score 6):

Based on matt's answer above, I think there is a less complicated version possible.

```
class TimerHolder : ObservableObject {
var timer : Timer!
@Published var count = 0
func start() {
    self.timer?.invalidate()
    self.count = 0
    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) {
        _ in
        self.count += 1
        print(self.count)
    }
  }
}
```

With `: ObservableObject`and `@Publish var count`

and in the View

```
@ObservedObject var durationTimer = TimerHolder()
...
Text("\(durationTimer.count) Seconds").onAppear {
        self.durationTimer.start()
      }
```

you can observe any change to the count variable and update the Text in the view accordingly.

As mentioned in other comments, make sure though, that the timer is not restarted unexpectedly due to an action recreating the view.