# Retrieve value from function with swift closure

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I want to gather information about user with firebase firestore, I have in a Class a function which do that, but I want share this information with my struct ContentView.

```
class UserData : ObservableObject {
    // Use Firebase library to configure APIs
    @Published var db = Firestore.firestore()

    @Published var WholeDocument : Array<String> = []

    func GetAllData(completion: @escaping (Array<String>) -> ())  {

        db.collection("Users").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                completion([""])
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    //print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                    self.WholeDocument.append(document.documentID)

                }
                completion(self.WholeDocument)
            }



        }
```

I try to gather this array in my contentView

```
func Connection()
    {

        self.Database.GetAllData{(tab) in
            if tab.count > 0 {

                self.WholeDocumentContentView = tab

            }
            else {
                 print("Not found")
            }

        }
}
```

How to retrieve WholeDocument array with closure ?
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the structure/question correctly, your goal is to access the `WholeDocument` array in another SwiftUI view. The way to do that could be:

```
class UserData : ObservableObject {

    // Use Firebase library to configure APIs
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()

    @Published var WholeDocument : Array<String> = []

    init() {
        db.collection("Users").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                completion([""])
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    // print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                    self.WholeDocument.append(document.documentID)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyContentView : View {

    @ObservedObject var database: UserData

    var body: some View {
        // access database.WholeDocument
        List(database.WholeDocument, id: \.self) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

That way, when you initialize `MyContentView` with an instance of `UserData`, you will be able to observe `WholeDocument` in that view.

Comment: It works thank you, does it have another method to do that with closure with @escape, maybe I didn't figure out the concept.

Comment: you should be able to run any function in `UserData` in an `.onAppear` closure or something else (if you want it to update on a constant interval, you can use matt's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56905649)) and pass `Connection()` as a closure, yes

Comment: Ok I understand, Thank you.