# Assigning an ObservedState’s published value to a state

Tags: swiftui, state, observableobject, observedobject

I have a state called time

```
@State var time = 0
```

and an ObservedObject called timerWrapper

```
@ObservedObject var timerWrapper = TimerWrapper()
```

time can be updated from a child view and I want to be also able to update it using the timerWrapper (theObservedObject), if I use this:

```
self.time = self.timerWrapper.remainingSeconds
```

and do this:

```
Text($time)
```

The text doesn’t update. It only works if I do this:

```
Text(self.timerWrapper.remainingSeconds)
```

I know that’s because when remainingSeconds is published it will reload the UI.
But how can I get around this? Reminder I have 2 possible sources that can updated time, this is why I’m not using the observed object directly when creating the Text in the viewbuilder.

Comment: Decide on who "owns" this data. And update that same source. Is there a reason why you can't pass `self.$timeWrapper.remainingSeconds` binding to the child view? Why do you need `@State var time`?

Comment: @NewDev yey It works! mmm... but wondering if that’s the best way to do it

Comment: If you have something external that can change the state, best to use a view model, i.e. an `ObservedObject` as the source of truth for the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update local state on view model published property (for whatever reason), here is a way to do this

```
Text(time)   // << not binding, just property
   .onReceive(timerWrapper.$remainingSeconds) { value in // listen for publisher $
      self.time = value
   }
```