# How would I be able to execute code (such as pushing a view) after a set amount of time | SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

What I mean is; **How would I be able to push a view (meaning navigate to another screen) after a (for example) 20-second timer?**  I'm developing an app through SwiftUI, but I only know so much.  I would be very thankful if someone could help me get through this.  Here's my code for the page before the view pushes.

```
struct SwiftUIView : View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationView() {
        VStack{
            Text("Thank you for your time.")
                .font(.headline)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .lineLimit(5)
                .padding(.horizontal, 50.0)
            Text("We'll be in touch shortly.")
                .font(.subheadline)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .lineLimit(5)
                .padding(.horizontal, 50.0)
                .padding(.bottom, 450.0)
        }
    }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
```

Here's an [image of the canvas.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3OtW.png)

> (My question is now being flagged as a duplicate of someone else's.  I
>   can explain why that's not true.  The question that I am "duplicating"
>   is none other than someone asking, "How do I change the text after a
>   certain amount of time," while my question is, "How do I push a view
>   after a certain amount of time."  Very close, but not a duplicate.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update text using timer in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56504410/how-to-update-text-using-timer-in-swiftui)

Comment: @Cristik Not at all the same, and the accepted answer there is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI you must use `NavigationView` and `NavigationLink` to navigate. You can also use `NavigationView` and `NavigationLink` to navigate programmatically with this API belonging to the `NavigationLink` struct:

```
/// Creates an instance that presents `destination` when active.
public init(destination: Destination, isActive: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder label: () -> Label)
```

So, you can do something like this (the exact code may depend on what you really need to get):

```
class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var navigate = false

    init() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+2) { //navigate after 2 secs
            self.navigate = true
        }
    }        
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var contentViewModel = ContentViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Text("Hello World!")
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(), isActive: $contentViewModel.navigate) {
                    EmptyView() //you don't need a view if you want to navigate programmatically
                }
            }
        }            
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Navigation complete!")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Unfortunately there's a bug in SwiftUI: if you run the code above you'll see that tapping on the back button in the detail view it makes the content view navigate again to the detail view. Just one time. If you tap on the back button again the bug won't occur anymore. This is a known issue (we're all waiting for Apple to fix this). You can override the default back button to fix this problem. It's a workaround, but we can't do better at the moment:

```
class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var navigate = false

    init() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+2) {
            self.navigate = true
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var contentViewModel = ContentViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Text("Hello World!")
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(contentViewModel: contentViewModel), isActive: $contentViewModel.navigate) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var contentViewModel: ContentViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Text("Navigation complete!")
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Text("Back").onTapGesture { //this is just an example, it's a plain text
                self.contentViewModel.navigate = false
            })
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You have two choices:

you can use

```
sleep(20)
// code
```

to stop execution of your entire code, or

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 20) {
    // code
}
```

to execute ONLY the code inside the closure after 20 seconds.

You have to insert this in the code that trigger the event related to the presentation of the new view:

```
struct SwiftUIView : View {

    @State var isNewViewShowed: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 20) {
                    isNewViewShowed.toggle()
                }
            }) {
                Text("Present New View")
            }
        }.sheet(isPresented: $isNewViewShowed) {
            NewView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Never `sleep`. Never `sleep`.

Comment: This is for a button, not the answer I was looking for.