# How can you display text for 2 seconds and then hide it in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

Hi can someone help me how can you display text for 2 seconds and then hide it in SwiftUI?

I have the text

Text("My Text")

and I want this text to be removed after 2 seconds

and another element to appear on the place of the text

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show what research you've undertaken, what you've already tried, what didn't work, code samples etc. Please read [ask] and [mcve] and then [edit] your question showing the _minimum_ code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: So I have Text("My Text") and i want this one to be displayed only for 2 sec. After the 2 sec. this one to be removed

Comment: [This may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56504410/how-to-update-text-using-timer-in-swiftui) @Johanna

Comment: Can you show the code you've written to try and achieve this?

Answer (score 15):

You can do it like this:

```
import SwiftUI

    struct ContentView: View {

        @State private var textSwitch = false

        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text((textSwitch ? "Text to show after 2 seconds" : "Text to show first"))
            }
            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                    self.textSwitch.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```